# apigee edge api proxy POST request body missing

Tags: apigee

I send a POST request with body to an api proxy.  From the Edge Trace, I see the body got 'eaten' or 'disappeared' as it entered the api proxy.

This only happens to specific api proxy.

Any idea what's the cause and any know fix?

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, we need more information. In particular, it's not so clear what it means for a body to disappear, to be honest. Maybe you could try a dump of the output, together with an estimation of how the output should be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have an AssignMessage Policy in the flow that includes something like this:

```
<Set>
   <Verb />
</Set>
```

If you Set the Verb to nothing, you end up with a 405 error on the backend because you Set the Verb to Null.